# htaccess and rewriting urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

currently i have a /en/ folder that is empty except for a .htaccess with the following

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php?language=en$1 [NC]
```

i use it to eliminate the need for

```
index.php?language=en
```

in all my URLs. I would like to modify the htaccess in a way that i no longer need the /en/ folder with nothing but the htaccess inside. ideally i would like an htaccess in my root folder that reads the url and if it is www.example.com/en/ to rewrite to www.example.com/index.php?language=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?language=en$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in .htaccess file in your root folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?language=en$1 [L]
```

Here $1 will append rest of the url as well. The condition will also help if you request your files using direct url.